# IP address to domain redirection in NGINX

Tags: nginx, ip, redirect, http-redirect

My server is running NGINX. My problem is my site is accessible by both IP address and the domain. But I want that when someone browse the IP address the user shoulde be redirected to my domain.
Example :: When any one browse through http://107.170.126.xxx he should be redirected to http://mydomain.com

Please can anybody help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

so you can add the server block in the sites-available configuration file like below

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 111.11.111.111;

return 301 $scheme://yourname.com$request_uri;
```

}

so above code will make sure that if you enter 111.11.111.111 it will redirect to http://yourname.com

make sure after editing the config file to reload nginx server

Answer (score 2):

It is known as IP Canonical Issue
You want your ip address to be redirected to your domain name

for that you can add following code in nginx server block or add an additional server block in nginx configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com 192.168.xxx.xx;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I use this configuration on my server; if you try an HTTP connection to the IP address of the VPS it will be redirected to my main web site.

Answer (score 0):

i solved redirect from ip adress http/https in ispconfig with:

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    listen *:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/clients/client1/web1/ssl/domain.example-le.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/clients/client1/web1/ssl/domain.example-le.key;

    server_name    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    return         301 https://domain.example;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
listen *:80;
listen *:443 ssl http2;

*#Required TLS Version*
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

*#SSL Certificate Path*
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/keyfiles/ssl_certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/keyfiles/ssl_cert.key;

*#IP Address*
server_name    000.111.222.333;

*#Domain Name to be redirected*
return         301 https://www.domainname.com/;
}
```